# Code coverage for selected packages

Tags: java, eclipse, code-coverage, codepro

I am looking for a code coverage tool, which helps me find coverage of selected packages in my workspace. 
Solution pertaining to CI or Eclipse is welcome.
I am aware that, I can manually calculate based off the numbers I get from code coverage tools in eclipse. But I am reluctant to do so and want to rely on automatically computed code coverage.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the **google CodePro**,

Reference : https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/features/codecoverage/code_coverage